# Attaching deserialized entities with duplicate relationship entities to DbContext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am deserializing entities from XML and trying to attach them to the DBContext. This works fine if there are no non-repeating entities. But in the case of duplicate entities this fails.

**My Db Context:**

```
public class Context : DbContext, IDisposable {
    public Context() : base("name=DefaultConnection") { }
    public static Context Create() { return new Context(); }
    public override int SaveChanges() {
        var addedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added);
        foreach (var entry in addedEntries) {
            var dbEntity = GetDbEntity(entry);
            if (dbEntity != null) {
                entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    private object GetDbEntity(DbEntityEntry entry) {
        var entityType = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entry.Entity.GetType());
        using (var context = new Context()) {
            var dbset = context.Set(entityType);
            var entityId = (Guid)GetPropValue(entry.Entity, "Id");
            var found = dbset.Find(entityId);
            return found;
        }
    }
    public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName) {
        return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
    }

    public DbSet<PurchaseOrder> PurchaseOrders { get; set; }
}
```

**Data Model:** (each has a `Guid Id` primary key)

```
PurchaseOrders -> LineItem -> TrackingCategory
```

**The problem arises when I have this type of object structure after deserializing:**

```
PurchaseOrder1 -> LineItem1 -> TrackingCategory1
               -> LineItem2 -> TrackingCategory1
```

The deserializer has created two separate objects for TrackingCategory. Is there a way to detect this in the SaveChanges() override and remove/ignore then duplicates or merge them.